# Akka save/persist only last state

Tags: scala, akka

I'm implementing a directory watcher with the Akka framework : it simply creates an Actor for each new file being created in the directory and materialize a stream with FileTailSource that send the content of the file to a Kafka topic.

I'd like to be able to recover from a crash without reading again the same lines in the file. For this reason an actor state stores the line offset for each file.

I use Akka Persistence journal to persist states and snapshot to reduce the  amount of records in journal (with deleteMessages).

It really is overkill as I only need to store the last state unlike a event sourced architecture. The LevelDB journal is also not an option as not supported on the AIX platform where the application is run, I'm stuck with the in-memory journal and its limitations.

Is there a lighter alternative to this architecture ? I could probably use a simple serialization to store the state to disk but I'm curious if this supported on Akka Persistence ?